# Windows Task Scheduler to Run batch file that calls vbscript that runs a macro

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, vba

I have a batch file that first runs a vbscript to open excel and run a macro. Then it chains 2 other batch files to complete the process. Everything works if I simply double-click on the first batch file and let it run.

When I try to create a windows task scheduler to run the first batch file, it says it completed successfully, but the results of the macro and the other 2 batch files do not get ran/outputted.

First batch file:

```
REM @ECHO OFF

cscript //nologo "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\SaveToCSV.vbs"


Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\SFDL2.bat"
Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\SFDL3.bat"
QUIT
```

.vbs file:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\VendorManagementReport-Import2.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "CopyToCSV"
xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

I don't think the other 2 batch files are relevant as it never actually creates the .csv file from the .xlsm workbook, which is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **`Call`** from the first batch file, to start the other two in the same context

```
REM @ECHO OFF

cscript //nologo "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\SaveToCSV.vbs"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\SFDL2.bat"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\conf\SFDL3.bat"

QUIT
```

Comment: Didn't change anything. Still says it ran successfully, but nothing actually happened. Those 2 other batch files are dependent on having the .csv file available. The .vbs portion is not creating the csv file from the macro which means the other 2 batch files won't do anything.